# VisualVM Cannot connect to 178.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx using service:jmx:rmi///

Tags: java, windows-7, port, visualvm, jvisualvm

I used visualvm last week on my notebook and it worked without any issues. When I wanted to use it yesterday I get the error: `VisualVM Cannot connect to 178.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx using service:jmx:rmi///...` once adding a jmx connection.

The odd thing here is that I have the same version of visualvm, java jdk, java security level, internet connection and windows 7 professional on the desktop computer where it still works.

- firewall disabled (didn't work)
- port forwarding (not needed as it works fine on the desktop computer with the same connection)
- additional firewalls or anti virus software is not present

The notebook is a dell and a few days ago it got a major bios and dell util update, but I don't think this should fall into account in this matter.

Do you have any idea what else it could be, or what else I could do to track down the issue?

FYI I have another WIN7 home computer where it still works and a partner reported that he is getting the same issue for some time now on his desktop and notebook. I'm really at the end of my expertise :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like network environment issue. You may trace the other port first. (like 80 port)

Comment: trace route port, seriously?

Comment: in case you mean nmap the port. nmap shows it open for both systems (desktop where it works and notebook where it doesn't work).

Comment: Do you sure that VisualVM network still working on your notebook?

Comment: Or the issue only happen on your rmi port?

Comment: `Do you sure that VisualVM network still working on your notebook?` How could I verify this?
`Or the issue only happen on your rmi port?`
mhh, what do you mean? compared to what?

Comment: Like use command `telnet 178.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx` on your notebook.

Comment: ahh, works the same as on the desktop. no connection issues as if using another non open port.

Comment: Next we need to check the rmi negotiation. Use the sniffer tool [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to look up rmi packet.
Compare these packets between your desktop and notebook.
You could use the `filter` on wireshark to focus on your rmi packets.

Comment: Won't be able to work on this before next year. I hope you don't mind helping me next year in case I can't figure it out on my own. Thanks for all the help so far.